# Incorrect $HOME env variable for a newly created user

Tags: linux, ubuntu

On my Ubuntu machine, I logged in as "olduser" and created "newuser" using the following command:

```
adduser --system --home /usr/share/newuser --no-create-home --ingroup newgroup --disabled-password --shell /bin/false newuser
```

This adds a new line:

```
newuser:x:104:1001::/usr/share/newuser:/bin/false
```

to my `/etc/passwd` file. But when I log into the machine as 'newuser', my home directory is set as `/home/olduser`.

```
echo $HOME
```

gives

```
/home/olduser
```

The same command mentioned above works as expected on a Debian machine but not on the Ubuntu machine.

Why could this be happening?

**Edit**

I tried changing the home directory using the command

```
usermod -m -d /usr/share/newuser newuser
```

This also didn't help.

Comment: Are you actually the new user? See with `id`. You set the shell to `/bin/false` so logging in interactively should not work.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not a programming question. Try [ubuntu.se].

Comment: If you post this question elsewhere, or it's migrated, please specify exactly how you login as `newuser`.

Comment: Thanks @KeithThompson, I moved the question to http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/293237/incorrect-home-env-variable-for-a-newly-created-user 
And added the info you requested.
You can close this question.
 Thanks!

Comment: No, I can't close the question. You can delete it.

Comment: I can't close it because it is answered

Answer (score 1):

Instead of changing the dir in `/etc/passwd` try `usermod` this way:

`usermod -m -d /newhome/username username`

Since you've already changed this file try logging out and in again.

Comment: I had tried that, but still the home directory doesn't change